# AsyncStorage.removeItem(key) not removing items unless App restarted or after several minutes

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I have a logout `Button` that binds to the following method.

```
async onLogoutButtonPress()  {
  await AsyncStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
  await AsyncStorage.removeItem('mobileNumber');
  await AsyncStorage.removeItem("businessId");
  await AsyncStorage.clear();
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
}
```

I understand that `AsyncStorage.removeItem` is an asynchronous operation and it returns a Promise. However notice that I am using `await` that waits for Promise to resolve before navigating to `Login`.

I also tried the alternate `then` syntax

```
AsyncStorage.removeItem(('accessToken')).then(() => {console.log('resolved') },
  () => { console.log('rejected') })
```

And all of them show as `resolved` in the console, but some how the items persist unless I close and restart the app. I am seeing this behavior on Android.

Why aren't the items getting removed until I restart the app ?
I am using expo for the build, if that matters.

I am using

```
import { AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
```

Here's the react-native version.

"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz",

Comment: `but some how the items persist unless I close and restart the app` please explain how do you know that the items persist. Also, what version of `AsyncStorage` are you using?

Comment: @Vencovsky for instance `await AsyncStorage.getItem('businessId');` still shows the businessId of previous logged in user for several minutes and then after several minutes updates to the new value.

Comment: Where do you import `AsyncStorage` from ? `react-native` ? Or the community version? Please be more clear on that

Comment: Updated question with version details and `import { AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';`

Comment: Importing from `react-native` is deprecated, you should use the version of the [react native community](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage)

Comment: Did it solve the problem?

Comment: It didn't because I am using Expo and Expo does not yet come with the community version of AsyncStorage. So I am stuck with the issue as I cannot eject expo

Comment: Can you use ```Redux``` with Expo?